# This document already has an 'XmlDeclaration' node

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode xmlnode, xmlroot;                  
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();                
con.ConnectionString = @"...snip...";
con.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Database Connected");
String sql = "select Pdf_tag,Styles from Xml_Tags";              
com = new SqlCommand(sql);           
da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);                
da.Fill(ds, "xml");                
maxrows = ds.Tables["xml"].Rows.Count;
StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(file,Encoding.Default,true);              
do
{                                           
        string line = objReader.ReadLine();
        string st1 = ">";
        string st2 = "</";
        int end = line.IndexOf(st2);
        if (end != -1 && end > 1)
        {
            st = line.IndexOf(st1);
            en = line.IndexOf(st2);
            int v = en - st;
            sub = line.Substring(st + 1, v - 1);                            
            rchtext.Text = rchtext.Text + sub + "\r\n"; 

            for (int i = 0; i < maxrows; i++)
            {
                dRow = ds.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];
                if(dRow[0].ToString ()!=line)
                {

                    XmlNode docNode = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
                    xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);

                    String sqll = "select Dtd_Tag,Dtd_Attribute_Name from Xml_Tags,Mapped_Tags_Attributes where Mapped_Tags_Attributes.Pdf_Tag=Xml_Tags.Pdf_Tag";
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqll);
                    SqlDataAdapter daa = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqll, con);
                    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                    daa.Fill(ds1, "xml");                                    
                    dRow1 = ds1.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];

                    string name = XmlConvert.EncodeName(dRow1.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    xmlnode = xmldoc.CreateElement(name);

                    XmlNode Doc = xmldoc.CreateDocumentType(name, null, "E:\\Rachana_mds\\proj\\pdfextraction\\docbook.dtd", null);
                    xmldoc.AppendChild(Doc);

                    String sqlll = "select Dtd_Attribute_Name,Dtd_Tag from Mapped_Tags_Attributes,Xml_Tags where Mapped_Tags_Attributes.Pdf_Tag=Xml_Tags.Pdf_Tag";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlll);
                    SqlDataAdapter dt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlll,con);
                    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                    dt.Fill(ds2, "xml");
                    dRow2 = ds2.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];

                    xmlroot = xmldoc.CreateElement(dRow1.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlroot);
                    XmlAttribute xmlatt = xmldoc.CreateAttribute(dRow2.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    xmlroot.AppendChild(xmlnode);
                        xmlnode.InnerText=sub;                                                                                                                                                                                     
                }                             

           }                               

        }                   
}                                                                
while (objReader.Peek() != -1);
//string filename = @"E:" + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Minute + ".xml";
string filename = @"E:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")+".xml";
xmldoc.Save(filename); 
MessageBox.Show("Done");
con.Close();
```

Comment: @rachana - What's the question?

Comment: Great. Perhaps it does "already have an 'XmlDeclaration' node". What's the question? -1 ...(I hope that's not your real SA login)

Comment: error for this line.. xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);... wat is wrong sir..

Comment: @rachana - Be specific like what are you trying to do, what error are you getting and error details.

Comment: when i run the application i am getting error for xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode) line... as This document already has an 'XmlDeclaration' node.

Comment: when i run the application i am getting error for xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode) line... as This document already has an 'XmlDeclaration' node

Comment: why not use LINQ to XML for this things, it is easier.

Comment: how to use that.. i am taking elements and attributes from database... so i cant use that...

Answer (score 3):

You only need 1 xmldeclaration node in the document. You're attempting to add one for each iteration of the loop..

Answer (score 2):

with your `for` loop with `i=0` this code runs

```
XmlNode docNode = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);
```

and adds an `XMLDeclaration` to `xmldoc`, all things end in the for loop with `i=0`, then `i` becomes `1` with `i++` afterwards the same `for` loop works for `i=1` and this code works again

```
XmlNode docNode = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);
```

which tries to add another `XMLDeclaration` to `xmldoc` and gives you that error you mentioned. What you can do to get rid of this error is writing this code

```
XmlNode docNode = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);
```

outside your loops both `for` and `do-while` and based on what you want you can take this code

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
```

just before this one

```
XmlNode docNode = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);
```

but then you will have so many `xmldoc` and you will lose them if you don't save them in a `List`.

In addition to all those above, I suggest you to write your codes more object-oriented.You can create another method for that `for` loop for example.Try to seperate your methods, divide and conquer.